# How reliable is Clonezilla for backing up and restoring Windows Vista Home Premium?

Tags: windows-vista, backup, norton-ghost, clonezilla

I am of course talking about full "system image" backups, similar to the old Norton Ghost. Should I look at other options? There are quite a few paid and free choices, but Clonezilla looks the best based on their own website.

Answer (score 3):

while "the old Norton Ghost" is still my tool of choice, Clonezilla backups are just as reliable as any other drive image.

if you're still looking for alternatives, check **[Drive SnapShot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/)** or if you prefer 'free' then there is **[Drive Image XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm)**. while DIXML isn't as fast as the other programs you can get a **[BartPE plugin](http://www.runtime.org/peb.htm)** from their website, which makes it an attractive choice

Answer (score 0):

this program is also free:

[EASEUS Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/) is a potent freeware providing sector-by-sector disk/partition clone regardless of your operating system, file systems and partition scheme by creating a bootable CD. The sector-by-sector method assures you a copy 100% identical to the original. Disk Copy can be used for copy, cloning, or upgrading your original small hard drive to a new larger drive. Simply speaking, it can copy anything from the old hard drive including the deleted, lost files and inaccessible data. So, the freeware is a perfect tool for Data Recovery Wizard to recover files from a backup disk.